# Do we suppose that $y$ is the variable at which $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In my notes there is the following:

The solution of the problem

$$u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0, x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0 \\ u(x, 0)=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R} \\ u_t(x,0)=g(x)$$

is $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[f(x+ct)+f(x-ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(s)ds$$ where $f \in D^2(\mathbb{R}), g\in D^1(\mathbb{R})$

When we want to differentiate $f(x+ct)$ in respect to $t$ do we set $y=x+ct$ and suppose that $y$ is the variable at which $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ ??

Comment: you may want to review/look up  chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f(x+ct))=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x+ct)f'(x+ct)=cf'(x+ct)$, this obtained by the composite function differentiation rule $(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)g'$. You do not need a substitution, the fact that $f$ is differentiable on all of $\Bbb R$ is enough.